# one class for both a set and a dictionary (map)

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, containers

I want to implement both Hash-Table and Ballanced-Binary-Tree (AVL, specifically), for both needs of a **set** and a **dictionary** (map).

For the first purpose, there is only a Key class, and for the second, there is Key and Data (or Value).

The two versions share a lot of functionality (especially in the tree case), so I really don't want to implement twice :

```
template<class Key> class AVLTree;
template<class Key, class Val> class AVLTree;
```

How can I elegantly make one "HashTable" class, and respectively one "AVLTree" class, with one template signature and use them for both purposes (with possibly wrapper/derived classes [[Un]Ordered] "Set" and "Map"?

(No, I don't want to use STL)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is: Do it as the STL does it.

Introduce the most general form of `AVLTree` that you need:

```
template <class K, class V, class KeyOfValue, class Compare>
class AVLTree;
```

(see [_Rb_tree_base](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_tree.h) as a reference). In this context, an `AVLTree` only ever stores `Value`s. But for reasons of comparing values, it is capable of retrieving the `Key` of a `Value` by means of an `KeyOfValue` object.

Using this, your `dictionary` application is obvious. A `set` can then be modeled by using the same type for `Key` and `Value` as well as identity for `KeyOfValue`. (Probably you don't want to spell this out each time. Just use a wrapper template for that.)

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about that KeyOfValue, but doesn't it assume that Value always contains Key in some sense? What if I want to just make a dictionary of, say, names of days and their numbers {"Sunday" : 1, "Monday" : 2, ... }, whould I have to implement a function that gives me a name by the number? so what's the point of having a dictionary then? Or do you mean that I'll have to use "pair<Key,Value>" as "Value" from the outside (when instanciating the clas)?

Comment: You'd have to use `pair<string, int>` as `Value` in this example. Yes this assumes the `Value` contains everything you want to store. But IMHO this is not a problem since you want to store all this anyways.